# Exibir valores monetários de forma simples

Tags: javascript, html, html5

bom dia!

Qual seria a forma **mais** **simples** de se exibir valores monetários com o Javascript? Eu consegui limitar as casas decimais usando o `.toFixed(2)`. Só que a parte inteira fica mais ou menos assim `10510.20` eu queria que fosse `10.520,20`. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa função: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: Mas esse resultado desejado seria retorno de que?

Answer (score 1):

Usa esta função sempre me deu um jeito enorme para este problema:

```
function format_num(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: Não seria x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");  Ponto ao invés de virgula em g, ",") .Se possível coloque um executar na sua resposta para testar

Comment: não porque o autor queria em virgulas

Comment: não, ele diz "eu queria que fosse 10.520,20" separador de milhar ponto e decimal virgula